# Google Colab: Cannot Import any Libaries in Notebook / ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

My Google Colab notebook suddenly stopped working normally. Now, it does not even import existing Google Colab libraries.

I tried the following code on a brand new Colab notebook:

```
import panda as pd
```

And this is the error message I received:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f542dbfa5144> in <module>()
----> 1 import panda as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'panda'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My notebooks used to work perfectly fine, with all the libraries loading properly. It suddenly stopped last night. I am just doing tutorials with minimal memory use. Did I exceed some Google Colab use limits without knowing?

Comment: Did you mean `import pandas as pd` (missed `s`)? If you really need `panda` package, then try to run `!pip install panda`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import pandas as pd`, not panda.

If still not found, use `!pip install pandas` or google install pandas in python, you will get the code in py.org site.